# In Perl, how would you search a file for a string then print the line that it's on?

Tags: string, perl, printing, line, match

This may seem a little remedial.

I can search a file, and I can print a line, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to put the two together.

Answer (score 6):

Just increment a counter every time you read a line.

```
my $line;
while (<>) {
   ++$line;
   print "$line: $_" if /foo/;
}
```

That said, Perl already does that for you.

```
while (<>) {
   print "$.: $_" if /foo/;
}
```

If you want to support multiple files,

```
while (<>) {
   print "$ARGV:$.: $_" if /foo/;
   close(ARGV) if eof;  # Reset line counter for each file.
}
```

(The lack of parens on `eof` is significant.)

Comment: Might want to print `$ARGV` too in case `@ARGV` contains multiple files.

Comment: If you want to support multiple files, you'll need to add `close ARGV if eof;` to reset the counter for each file. (The lack of parens on `eof` is significant.) @hobbs